# How to fetch data from a list of DocumentSnapshot?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is a stream which has a list of DocumentSnapshot. I am not able to get the data from this stream.How can I fetch the data from this stream?

```
Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo.collection(collectionRef:
collectionReference)
.within(center: center, radius: radius1, field: field);
```

Comment: to have an answer to your question try to make it easy to understand it. please follow the instruction on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: yeah I did my best. Actually this is first time using stack overflow. hope I get better at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here after some Work I solved this. This can be implemented using a .listen function of the stream.

```
stream.listen((event) {                                                                       
      int length=event.length;
      for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
      {
        if(event[i]["email"]!= user.email)
        randomUser.add("${event[i]["email"]}");                                             
      }
```